# Use one app for several uwsgi instances

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, multi-tenant, saas

I have found a lot of examples explaining how we can use uwsgi and emperor mode to achieve multiple apps deployment. This means for me: several apps folder with one vassal (ini, socket, application.py) per app.

I was not yet able to find examples of configurations where there were only one app folder with multiple vassals. This should allow me to serve a multi-tenants app (each customer has its own database). I tested this with two instances. This "seems" to work well.

1. Is this a good practice or do you have similar setup ?
2. Does this provide complete isolation between vassals instances ?

Here is my setup. I am using nginx/uwsgi/python stack (I make use of [emperor_pg module](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ImperialMonitors.html#pg-scan-a-postgresql-table-for-configuration)). This setup allows uwsgi to spawn one vassal per customer A and B. Customers are using url : customerN.mydomain.com/fe1/web

**Nginx config :**

```
# This virtual host catches all incoming traffic from port 80 (security should be considered if not talking on local
# network)
server {
        listen 80;
        # We capture here the subdomain. It is used to designate a customer entity.
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.mydomain\.fr$;


        # We use a pattern for creating sockets name and path.
        # This allows to spawn vassals automatically by detecting changes in the vassals pg table (emperor_pg)
        # Pattern used is : /tmp/$subdomain$appname.sock


        location ~favicon\.ico$ {
            root /opt/app-current/web/;
        }

        location ~^\/(?<app_name>.+)\/web\/ {

            root /opt/web-content/$subdomain/;
        }

        location ~^\/(?<app_name>.+)\/ {

            # Routing to socket designated by standard pattern
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix://tmp/$subdomain$app_name.sock;

        }

        # When calling root of entity's subdomain, we launch the default app by routing traffic to index.socket
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix://tmp/$subdomain.sock;
        }
}
```

**The emperor upstart script** using emperor_pg :

```
# Emperor configuration upstart script in `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` :
# uWSGI - Manage uWSGI Application Server

description "uWSGI Emperor Mode"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn


# We use pg mode. This allows to scan a postgresql database.
# requires sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-emperor-pg

exec /usr/bin/uwsgi --uid www-data --gid www-data --plugin emperor_pg --emperor "pg://host=dbserver.com.com user=saasautomator dbname=saasautomator;SELECT name,config,ts,uid,gid,socket FROM vassals" --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log
```

**And an example of vassals** conf files in database. They are using the same application folder :

```
saasautomator=> SELECT * FROM vassals;
 idvassals |              name               |                             config                             |         ts          |  uid  |  gid  |                socket                 
-----------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------
         3 | customerAfe1.ini  | [uwsgi]                                                       +| 2004-10-19 10:23:54 | uwsgi | uwsgi | /tmp/customerAfe1.sock
           |                                 |  master = true                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  vaccum = true                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  chdir = /opt/app/                       +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  plugins = python                                             +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  wsgi-file = /opt/app/fe1/application.py +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  processes = 4                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  threads = 2                                                  +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  stats = 127.0.0.1:9191                                        |                     |       |       | 
         4 | customerBfe1.ini | [uwsgi]                                                       +| 2004-10-19 10:23:55 | uwsgi | uwsgi | /tmp/customerBfe1.sock
           |                                 |  master = true                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  vaccum = true                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  chdir = /opt/app/                       +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  plugins = python                                             +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  wsgi-file = /opt/app/fe1/application.py +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  processes = 4                                                +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  threads = 2                                                  +|                     |       |       | 
           |                                 |  stats = 127.0.0.1:9192                                        |                     |       |       | 
(2 rows)
```

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if this question fits on stackoverflow, but I will answer it anyway...

Comment: Thanks for helping. Sorry for having used the wrong place. Where would you have asked this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "Is this a good practice or do you have similar setup ?"

I do have similar setup. I won't answer if it's good practice, because it's opinion based, but there are small differences between this and copying code base for every customer. Main difference is: if someone will break into one app and he will be able to modify it's code, it will affect all apps... But if there are no differences in configuration of apps that will allow breaking in such way one, but not other - it won't matter. If someone breaks into one, he can reproduce that on others...

Also fixing changes that were made after hacking your app will be easier with shared codebase.

I can't see any other difference that will matter...

#### "Does this provide complete isolation between vassals instances ?"

Not complete, as mentioned before, but anything else can be isolated. This is like sharing one library between applications in system, which happens all the time. With proper configuration, you can also separate databases and other resources.

If filesystem permissions are applied correctly, you can limit ability to change code of your application by itself, so it will limit ability to change code by some hacker.